# Parsing a CSV file and read a specific column

Tags: python, read-csv

I have a CSV file that is the output of a hydrological model. I need to read a specific column of this file but because of complex structure, pandas.read_csv cannot do that. I would be grateful if somebody can help me (For example, I need to read the Rain column values).

[Please download the file from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aPLiRRF48CE2bJEzHQ_rupLrdikI-LZ2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Looks like that "csv file" has a whole bunch of lines at the top that aren't csv at all...

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: You're going to need to pre-process that file (manually or programmatically) to extract the table you want. Python also has its own [csv parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). I imagine pandas' parser is meant for data with a more table-like structure.

Comment: I need to calibrate the hydrological model automatically. Therefore, every time this csv file should be opened without any manual pre-process to let the optimization method to check multiple parameters values and the corresponding model results

Comment: Can you post a smaller example CSV file as text that we can copy? Writing temporary preprocessed files as a program executes is normal if you need to trim lines above and below the table you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is not a standard csv format. The program that output's this might have a better way to export the file. But if not and this is your only option you can just parse the file manually like this:

```py
rain_values = []

with open('AnnAGNPS_TBL_Gaging_Station_Data_Hyd.csv','r') as f:
    # skip first lines until the data begins
    while not next(f).startswith('Day'): pass

    # read lines of data
    for line in f:
        try:
            # append index 6 which is the data you want from the Rain column
            rain_values.append(line.split(',')[6].strip())
        except IndexError:
            # if we got this error it's because we've reached the end of the data section
            break

print(rain_values)
```

If you want to have a pandas dataframe with the csv data you can do something like this to load only the data you want:

```py
import pandas
with open('AnnAGNPS_TBL_Gaging_Station_Data_Hyd.csv','r') as f:
    # skip first lines until the data begins
    while not next(f).startswith('Day'): pass
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        if line == '\n': break
        lines.append(line.split(','))
    pandas.DataFrame(lines)
```

Comment: Nice answer. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan for some well-defined text in the file that tells you where the table of interest starts. Then, you can either start reading the CSV right away, or save the smaller sample to a temporary file on disk for further processing.

Handling data that is not strictly defined is always a bit dodgy, so it's a good idea to insert sanity checks as you go. The script starting to crash when input changes is better than silently generating bad data.

```
import csv

with open("thefile") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    # scan for wanted table marker
    for row in reader:
        if row and row[0] == "POLLUTANT LOADING TABLE- Hydrograph":
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError("No data table found")
    # skip 3 line header but add some sanity checks while we're here
    for wanted, row in zip(["simulation", "Gregorian", "Day"], reader):
        if not row or wanted != row[0]:
            raise ValueError("Invalid file")
    # grab a single column to end of file
    my_col = [row[whatever] for row in reader]
```